# What is the precedence of operator used here in for loop

Tags: c++, c, c++11, operators

What precedence expression - `k <= jp && k <= jz - i`   takes in the following for loop.
If I have to put braces for this expression, how do I consider..?

```
for (fw = 0.0, k = 0; k <= jp && k <= jz - i; k++)
```

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence

Answer (score 2):

`k <= jp && k <= jz - i`  is grouped as `(k <= jp) && (k <= (jz - i))`.

In `for (fw = 0.0, k = 0; k <= jp && k <= jz - i; k++)`, the semicolons separate the parts completely; `k <= jp && k <= jz - i` is not mixed with the items before or after it.

Answer (score 2):

You can read more about order of precedence at [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence).

It's better to add parentheses in your code if you are not sure about the order of precedence.

There are two reasons to use parenthesis around the terms of an exprssion.

1. To control the order of precedence.
2. To make the code more readable.

In your case, I think the code will be more readable by using:

```
for (fw = 0.0, k = 0; (k <= jp) && (k <= (jz - i)); k++)
```